# Facing this error in my Code : java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, android, firebase

**This is my logcat**

Complete details of the error are listed below:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:1384)
    at com.chetan.mobchat.Activities.MainActivity$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:115)
    at com.chetan.mobchat.Activities.MainActivity$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:81)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8218)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
```

This is my code in which there is an error in the line no 81 and 115 can any one help me in solving this error

**Code:**

81 ----

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Boolean aBoolean) {
    
                    String backgroundImage = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("backgroundImage");
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load(backgroundImage)
                            .into(binding.backgroundImage);
    
                    /* Toolbar Color */
                    String toolbarColor = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("toolbarColor");
                    String toolBarImage = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("toolbarImage");
                    boolean isToolBarImageEnabled = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getBoolean("toolBarImageEnabled");
    
    
    
                    if(isToolBarImageEnabled) {
                        Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                                .load(toolBarImage)
                                .into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull @NotNull Drawable resource, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                                        getSupportActionBar()
                                                .setBackgroundDrawable(resource);
                                    }
    
                                    @Override
                                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
    
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        getSupportActionBar()
                                .setBackgroundDrawable
                      115--                  (new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(toolbarColor)));
                    }
    
                }
            });
```

line no 81 and 115 is marked in the code above

Comment: It seems `toolbarColor` is an empty string at that point (which can't correctly parse in to a `Color`). Try to find out why.

Comment: As Joachim already mentioned in his comment, toolbarColor is empty. Are you sure that `String toolbarColor = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("toolbarColor");` does return the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

The internal implementation of the method `Color.parseColor(toolbarColor)` has a line of code as follows:
`long color = Long.parseLong(colorString.substring(1), 16)`

Since the `toolbarColor` is empty the `colorString.substring(1)` generates the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To solve this error pass a valid nonempty valid `toolbarColor`

Comment: can you explain more about how to solve the error

Comment: @chetanpatel Can you please tell me whats the value of `toolbarColor` ?